# Dynamically set default baseURL for axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

I can't get this to work, but if I set defaultBaseURL directly as a string i.e.'http://:' it works, with the following i keep getting 404's:

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, but i assume it's something to do with promises.

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import router from './router'
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    setBaseURL();
    
async function getIp() {
  axios.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")
    .then(x => {
      x = 'http://' + JSON.stringify(x.data.ip).replace(/"/g, '') + ':8081'
      return x
    });
}
async function setBaseURL() {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = await getIp();
}

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey seems like one of your async functions doesn't return any promises.
You can do it like this:

```js
async function getIp() {
  cosnt x = await axios.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")
  return 'http://' + JSON.stringify(x.data.ip).replace(/"/g, '') + ':8081'
}
```

or add a return to the `axios.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")`,
otherwise `await getIp()` doesn't know what it needs to await for, let me know if it helps. cheers.

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyKlimenchenko! It works on P.C but not on Android. Any idea why that could be?